# Can't unhide div tags after hiding them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically show and hide the contents of div tags based on whether a `<ul>` inside each one has all it's elements hidden or not.  I can successfully hide and show individual `<li>` elements based on the search, as well as hide the whole div if the `<ul`> has all its elements hidden.  However, I can't seem to unhide the `<div>` if the search text gets shortened.

Here's my html:

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3" readonly="true" />
<div class="azdiv" id="A">

<h2 id="a">A</h2>

    <ul class="azlist">
        <li><a href="#/australia/">Australia</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#/austria/">Austria</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="azdiv" id="B">

<h2 id="b">B</h2>

    <ul class="azlist">
        <li><a href="#/belgium/">Belgium</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#/brazil/">Brazil</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here's my javascript (using jquery)

```
$(function () {

jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {

        var filter = $(this).val();

        $("ul.azlist").find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().hide();

        $("ul.azlist").find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().show();

        $("div.azdiv").find("ul:not(:has(li:visible))").parent().hide();

        $("div.azdiv").find("ul:has(li:visible)").parent().show();
        var textbox3 = document.getElementById('textbox3');
        textbox3.value = $('ul.azlist').children(':visible').length;
    });
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snLu9ktv/)

Comment: Why is there a `:visible` in selector for `.show()`, a hidden element cannot be visible. A hidden parent also has hidden children. Just take the `:visible` out of `$("div.azdiv").find("ul:has(li:visible)").parent().show()`.

Comment: Oh wow that makes sense.  However now it always shows the div.  I'm trying to hide the whole div if the ul should be empty, and otherwise just hide the li elements that don't match the search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it by first checking to see how many results should be visible in each div given the search string, and then hiding/unhiding first the divs, and then the contents within.

```
$(function () {

jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
    return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$('#search').keyup(function () {

    var filter = $(this).val();

    $("div.azdiv").each(function () {

      if (filter.length == 0) {
        $(this).show();
        $(this).find("ul.azlist li").show();
      } else {
            if ($(this).find("ul.azlist a:Contains(" + filter + ")").length > 0) {
              $(this).show();
              $(this).find("ul.azlist a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().show();
              $(this).find("ul.azlist a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().hide();
            } else {
              $(this).hide();
            }
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just flip these two lines:

```
$("ul.azlist").find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().show();
$("div.azdiv").find("ul:not(:has(li:visible))").parent().hide();
```

It should work then. You were showing and then hiding the elements you wanted to show.